# Connecting text in a tikz-qtree with other text by arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I want to connect the NP[...], NP[...] text in the left daughter of the following tree with the NP[...], NP[...] in the right daughter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\feattab}[1]{[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1 ]\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\vform}{{\sc vform}\xspace}

\newcommand{\type}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\sc #1}\right\rangle$}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=4\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=8\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}] } } 
        [.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{bse},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}] } } lesen ]
        [.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}], V } } wird ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to achieve this with `\node` and `\draw`, but somehow this does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\feattab}[1]{[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1 ]\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\vform}{{\sc vform}\xspace}

\newcommand{\type}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\sc #1}\right\rangle$}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=4\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=8\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}] } } 
        [.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{bse},\\
              \sliste{ \node(lesen){NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}]}; } } lesen ]
        [.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ \node(wird){NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}]};, V } } wird ]
]
\draw[semithick,->] (lesen)..controls +(south east:5) and +(south west:5)..(wird);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I would also like to highlight the NP[...], NP[...] part by turning the background into gray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TiKZ-qtree manual says

> Inside a \Tree , in place of a node label, you can use a TikZ \node
>   command.

and you are trying to use a `node` inside a `node label` not instead of. If you include all your node label inside a `node`, it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\feattab}[1]{[\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1 ]\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\vform}{{\sc vform}\xspace}

\newcommand{\type}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\sc #1}\right\rangle$}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=4\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=8\baselineskip}}
\Tree[.V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}] } } 
        [.\node (lesen) {V\feattab{
              \vform \type{bse},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}] } } }; ]
        [.\node (wird) {V\feattab{
              \vform \type{fin},\\
              \sliste{ NP[\type{nom}], NP[\type{acc}], V } }}; ]
]
\draw[semithick,->] (lesen)..controls +(south east:5) and +(south west:5)..(wird);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think this works for the example at hand. But is there a general way to achieve what I described? The point is that the nodes in the trees are big and one may want to connect a specific item inside of a node to another item in another node.

Comment: @StefanMüller: You could try using [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) inside nodes, but my test was not successful. Another one, you can also `shift` your `anchors`: `draw ([shift={(...,...)lesen.south}...` and try to find the position where you want point.