# Connecting arbitrary text in `forest`

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics, forest

I already asked this question with regard to `tikz-qtree` ([Connecting text in a tikz-qtree with other text by arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144770/connecting-text-in-a-tikz-qtree-with-other-text-by-arrow)), but maybe there is a better way to do this in `forest`.

I have the following tree:

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}},
}



\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges
[V{[\textit{fin,} SUBCAT $<>$]}
        [1 NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1>$]}
                [2 NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                        [das Buch]]
                [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1,2>$]}
                        [3 NP{[\textit{dat}]}
                                [dem Mann]]
                        [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1,2,3>$]}
                                [gibt]]]]]  
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to connect the instances of `fin`by double arrows. The best way to do this would be to have some `\node` declaration around the various `fin`s and connect these nodes. But this somehow does not work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to just set the name as they are arealdy nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}},
}



\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
sn edges
[V{[\textit{fin,} SUBCAT $<>$]}
        [1 NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                [er]]
        [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1>$]},name=fin1  %new code
                [2 NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                        [das Buch]]
                [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1,2>$]},name=fin2 %new code
                        [3 NP{[\textit{dat}]}
                                [dem Mann]]
                        [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1,2,3>$]},name=fin3 %new code
                                [gibt]]]]]
\draw[<->] ($(fin1.south west)+(1,.1)$) -- ($(fin2.north west)+(.5,-.1)$);
\draw[<->] ($(fin2.south west)+(1,.1)$) -- ($(fin3.north west)+(.5,-.1)$);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I was not sure what you wanted to connect, you can use standard node anchors to move the arrows around or bend the arrows, etc.

[image]

Edit: for more fine grained control over the arrows origin and end it is possible to use tikzmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}},
}



    \begin{document}
        \begin{forest}
    sn edges
    [V{[\textit{fin,} SUBCAT $<>$]}
            [1 NP{[\textit{nom}]}
                    [er]]
            [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1\tikzmark{m1}>$]},name=fin1  %new code
                    [2 NP{[\textit{acc}]}
                            [das Buch]]
                    [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<\tikzmark{m2}1,2>$]},name=fin2 %new code
                            [3 NP{[\textit{dat}]}
                                    [dem Mann]]
                            [V{[\textit{fin}, SUBCAT $<1,2,3>$]},name=fin3 %new code
                                    [gibt]]]]]
    \draw[<->] ($(fin1.south west)+(1,.1)$) -- ($(fin2.north west)+(.5,-.1)$);
    \draw[<->] ($(fin2.south west)+(1,.1)$) -- ($(fin3.north west)+(.5,-.1)$);
    \end{forest}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
       \draw[<->](pic cs:m1)--(pic cs:m2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution handles the whole node as one object. I want to connect arbitrary text within these nodes. For instance connecting the `1`. Your solution seems to use absolute shifts and hence seems to be font dependent. I was trying something like `\node (fin1) {\textit{fin}}` within the tree nodes, but this did not work.

Comment: @StefanMüller I added another approach that uses tikzmarks for more fine grained position control. Notice that it needs two compilations to set the drawing straight.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not take into account the size of the text. It is just one point, right? I could not refer to the top of the lower `1`, could I?

Comment: @Stefan Muller You can shift the reference point using `calc`, so something like `($(pic cs:mark1)+(0em,1em)$)` or whatever. Use `em`s as unit measure so that the font size is taken into account. The shifting will be very small anyway.